# What date RFC does Twitter use?

Tags: datetime, twitter, rfc

Doc use : Tue Apr 07 22:52:51 +0000 2009 
as an example.
Can anyone identify the rfc? 
Cheers

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I can't say "there is no standard of that format" of course, because I very well may have just missed it. But when I started working with the Twitter API I did search for awhile to find the standard they are using and couldn't find a match. I ended up having to define a custom format (c#):

```
DateTime.ParseExact(twitterDateString,
                    "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss %K yyyy",
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat);
```

Answer (score 7):

Neither [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.3) nor [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339) allow for separating the year from the month and day like that. If twitter was trying to be compliant, they blew it on the two most relevant IETF standards and on [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Answer (score 0):

Convert dateTime Objet to RFC 3339

```
startDate = datetime(2019, 11, 1, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=timezone.utc).isoformat('T')
endDate = datetime(2019, 12, 6, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=timezone.utc).isoformat('T')
```