# Converting Twitter DateTime to Localtime with adding UTC offset

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetime, twitter

I am developing a twitter app. The datetime string returned by twitter API is of format "Tue Jan 24 08:42:31 +0000 2012". The API will return the offset value also. For (UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi, the offset value will be "19800".

How will I convert this datetime string to local datetime with adding UTC offset.

Can anybody please throw some light on this?

Comment: Here is a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917810/what-date-rfc-does-twitter-use). Unfortunately, the twitter datetime does not conform to an RFC, so you will have to come up with the parsing code on your own. A response in the link gives some example code. The relevant method here is [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx)

Comment: Hi Cameron, I am already using this way of parsing. `DateTime.ParseExact(twitterDateOffset, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`. But this is returning in localtime. How can I modify this function to return UTC value?

Comment: Have you tried DateTime.ToUniversalTime() after parsing?

Answer (score 0):

Offset value is stored in seconds, you can just create a `DateTime` for string you received from Twitter and call it method `AddSeconds`