# How to parse Twitter's Created At property to .Net Date

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, twitter

Twitter's API is returning a data value that looks like this:

```
created_at = "Thu Nov 14 15:50:44 +0000 2013"
```

How do I parse that as a date in C#?

I've tried both:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(item.created_at)
```

and

```
DateTime.Parse(item.created_at)
```

But both fail to parse the date. Ideas?

Comment: answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/2917849/841176

Comment: @Kostyan - thanks, that is the answer. I think I'll close this one since it's basically a duplicate.